# How to sync folders from PC to Google Drive without modifying any of the existing folders in Drive?

Tags: google-sync, google-backup-and-sync

I have certain folders in my Google Drive. For example- Folder1, Folder2, Folder3.
Now I have a 'Folder4' on my PC and I wish to sync it to Drive, but the other folders which are already there on my Drive - I want those to remain untouched.
In future, I want the two-way sync to happen only between the two 'Folder4's - the one on my PC, and another on my Drive.

I have read multiple resources, but couldn't find any piece of information which describes such a scenario. Can someone please suggest?

Comment: Could you perhaps list the resources you've read so we do not suggest them to you agan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I started the sync, I found that the file/folder from the PC gets created in Drive under the 'Computers' section, whereas the existing file/folder remains as it is under the 'My Drive' section. So that way the file/folder in 'My Drive' section would remain untouched.